# how to redirect to refinery dashboard page instead of application root to page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

i have a rails 3.2.8 application that uses devise 2.0.0 for authentication i integrated refinerycms with this application it is integrated successfully now problem is when user hit

`localhost/refinery` it takes me to refinery login page but after
successfull login it redirects back to my application home page rather
than refinerycms dashboard page.

So i want to know how to redirect to the
refinery dashboard after refinery successfull login procedure.
I have route mount `Refinery::Core::Engine`,

```
:at => '/' root to:'projects#index'
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom devise controller that redirects the user to the place you want once they are logged in:

Create the Custom Controller: controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

```
  class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:destroy] 

  def new 
    super
  end

  def create
      #Can edit this for custom redirect
      super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end

  protected

  def stub_options(resource)
     methods = resource_class.authentication_keys.dup
     methods = methods.keys if methods.is_a?(Hash)
     methods << :password if resource.respond_to?(:password)
     { :methods => methods, :only => [:password] }
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      #Can edit this for custom redirect
      super
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    super
  end

  private

end
```

then tell devise to use that controller in your routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "users/sessions"}
```